# If $x≥0$ and $0≤x<ϵ$, for all $ϵ>0$, then $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to let ϵ=0.5x, but find ϵ might be zero in this way, which is contradict to for all ϵ>0. Is this statement false?

Comment: Suppose $x>0$. What can you conclude?

Comment: The statement says that the conclusion follows if the inequality is true for all $\epsilon > 0$. Fixing $\epsilon$ at a particular value is not meaningful, especially if that value is possibly outside of the range of $\epsilon$ that you are allowed to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it by contradiction.

Suppose $x \ge 0$ but $ x \ne 0$. So, $x > 0$

Then for $\epsilon = x/ 2 \gt 0$ we have $ x \not \lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement means that x is non negative yet it is strictly smaller than every positive real number. Hence x=0 is the only possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Argue by contradiction. Assume $x>0.$ Then consider $\epsilon=\dfrac x2>0.$ By assumption we have that $$0\le x<\epsilon =\dfrac x2,$$ from where it must be $x=0.$ This gives a contradiction with the assumption $x>0.$

So, we have shown that $x=0.$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\forall \epsilon>0)\; \;0\leq x\leq \epsilon$$

$$\implies (\forall n>0)\;\; 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{n}$$

$$\implies 0\leq x \leq \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

$$\implies x=0.$$

Answer (score -1):

You can either take the limit of $\epsilon \to 0$ or suppose that $x \not= 0$ and try to find a contradiction.